# Python Timezone conversion

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

How do I convert a time to another timezone in Python?

Comment: Python 3.9: [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html)

Comment: You could also have linked your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67354610/1843452 @FObersteiner

Answer (score 142):

I have found that the best approach is to convert the "moment" of interest to a utc-timezone-aware datetime object (in python, the timezone component is not required for [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) objects).

Then you can use [astimezone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) to convert to the timezone of interest ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2090122/2697658)).

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

utcmoment_naive = datetime.utcnow()
utcmoment = utcmoment_naive.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)

# print "utcmoment_naive: {0}".format(utcmoment_naive) # python 2
print("utcmoment_naive: {0}".format(utcmoment_naive))
print("utcmoment:       {0}".format(utcmoment))

localFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

timezones = ['America/Los_Angeles', 'Europe/Madrid', 'America/Puerto_Rico']

for tz in timezones:
    localDatetime = utcmoment.astimezone(pytz.timezone(tz))
    print(localDatetime.strftime(localFormat))

# utcmoment_naive: 2017-05-11 17:43:30.802644
# utcmoment:       2017-05-11 17:43:30.802644+00:00
# 2017-05-11 10:43:30
# 2017-05-11 19:43:30
# 2017-05-11 13:43:30
```

So, with the moment of interest in the local timezone (a time that [exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997577/python-timezone-conversion/18646797#comment40107516_18646797)), you convert it to utc like this ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7065242/2697658)).

```
localmoment_naive = datetime.strptime('2013-09-06 14:05:10', localFormat)

localtimezone = pytz.timezone('Australia/Adelaide')

try:
    localmoment = localtimezone.localize(localmoment_naive, is_dst=None)
    print("Time exists")

    utcmoment = localmoment.astimezone(pytz.utc)

except pytz.exceptions.NonExistentTimeError as e:
    print("NonExistentTimeError")
```

Comment: beware, local time may be ambiguous and the given string might not correspond to any existing time e.g., due to DST transitions. Provide `localize(is_dst=None)` if you want to raise an exception in such cases.

Comment: Going to save this answer off somewhere as I think I will reference it at least twice a week :P

Answer (score 61):

Using [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"
timezonelist = ['UTC','US/Pacific','Europe/Berlin']
for zone in timezonelist:

    now_time = datetime.now(timezone(zone))
    print now_time.strftime(fmt)
```

Comment: note: it prints *different* time moments in *different* timezones. OP asks about **the same** time moment in different timezones.

Comment: @jfs No it doesn't - I just ran this and it printed `2018-07-12 13:46:17 UTC+0000`, `2018-07-12 06:46:17 PDT-0700`, and `2018-07-12 15:46:17 CEST+0200`, all of which represent the same instant in time.

Comment: @MarkAmery: try to add microseconds to the `fmt` (`"%f"`) to see that the time instances are different.

Comment: @jfs Ah, I misunderstood your comment! I thought you were asserting that the moments represented completely different moments in time (i.e. hours apart), not just that they were separated by the few microseconds between the `datetime.now(...)` calls.

Answer (score 54):

**Python 3.9 adds the [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html) module** so now only the the standard library is needed!

```
>>> from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> d = datetime(2020, 10, 31, 12, tzinfo=ZoneInfo('America/Los_Angeles'))
>>> d.astimezone(ZoneInfo('Europe/Berlin'))  # 12:00 in Cali will be 20:00 in Berlin
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 31, 20, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Berlin'))
```

[Wikipedia list of available time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

---

Some functions such as `now()` and `utcnow()` return timezone-unaware datetimes, meaning they contain **no timezone information**. I recommend only requesting timezone-aware values from them using the keyword `tz=ZoneInfo('localtime')`.

If `astimezone` gets a timezone-unaware input, it **will assume it is local time**, which can lead to errors:

```
>>> datetime.utcnow()  # UTC -- NOT timezone-aware!!
datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 22, 39, 57, 376479)
>>> datetime.now()     # Local time -- NOT timezone-aware!!
datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 2, 0, 39, 57, 376675)

>>> datetime.now(tz=ZoneInfo('localtime'))  # timezone-aware
datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 2, 0, 39, 57, 376806, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='localtime'))
>>> datetime.now(tz=ZoneInfo('Europe/Berlin'))  # timezone-aware
datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 2, 0, 39, 57, 376937, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Berlin'))
>>> datetime.utcnow().astimezone(ZoneInfo('Europe/Berlin'))  # WRONG!!
datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 22, 39, 57, 377562, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Berlin'))
```

---

**Windows** [has no](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html#data-sources) system time zone database, so here an extra package is needed:

```
pip install tzdata
```

---

There is a backport to allow use in **Python 3.6 to 3.8**:

```
sudo pip install backports.zoneinfo
```

Then:

```
from backports.zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
```

Comment: How do you handle then the `datetime.now(tz=ZoneInfo('localtime'))` timezone-aware object? Example: `ZoneInfoNotFoundError: 'No time zone found with key localtime'`. Is `localtimezone` meant to be replaced? What to do with a `EEST` local timezone for example, which is unknown to zoneinfo?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris You have to install `tzdata` as I described in my answer

Comment: Already installed. But I tried again, same error.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris I can replicate your error, it looks like `localtime` is only available on Linux then. You could try `from dateutil.tz import tzlocal` as recommended in this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/q/2720319/2111778) or just pass an explicit time zone.

Answer (score 36):

```
import datetime
import pytz

def convert_datetime_timezone(dt, tz1, tz2):
    tz1 = pytz.timezone(tz1)
    tz2 = pytz.timezone(tz2)

    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    dt = tz1.localize(dt)
    dt = dt.astimezone(tz2)
    dt = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    return dt
```

-

- `dt`: date time string
- `tz1`: initial time zone
- `tz2`: target time zone

-

```
> convert_datetime_timezone("2017-05-13 14:56:32", "Europe/Berlin", "PST8PDT")
'2017-05-13 05:56:32'

> convert_datetime_timezone("2017-05-13 14:56:32", "Europe/Berlin", "UTC")
'2017-05-13 12:56:32'
```

-

```
> pytz.all_timezones[0:10]
['Africa/Abidjan',
 'Africa/Accra',
 'Africa/Addis_Ababa',
 'Africa/Algiers',
 'Africa/Asmara',
 'Africa/Asmera',
 'Africa/Bamako',
 'Africa/Bangui',
 'Africa/Banjul',
 'Africa/Bissau']
```

Comment: Delete blank lines in the function so it will run in REPL

Answer (score 21):

##### Time conversion

To convert a time in one timezone to another timezone in Python, you could use **datetime.astimezone():**

so, below code is to convert the local time to other time zone.

- **datetime.datetime.today()** - return current the local time
- **datetime.astimezone()**     - convert the time zone, but we have to pass the time zone.
- **pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')** -passing the time zone to pytz module
- **Strftime** - Convert Datetime to string

```
# Time conversion from local time
import datetime
import pytz
dt_today = datetime.datetime.today()   # Local time
dt_India = dt_today.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')) 
dt_London = dt_today.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/London'))
India = (dt_India.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
London = (dt_London.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
print("Indian standard time: "+India+" IST")
print("British Summer Time: "+London+" BST")
```

##### List all the time zones

```
import pytz
for tz in pytz.all_timezones:
    print(tz)
```

Answer (score 12):

To convert a time in one timezone to another timezone in Python, you could [use `datetime.astimezone()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone):

```
time_in_new_timezone = time_in_old_timezone.astimezone(new_timezone)
```

Given `aware_dt` (a `datetime` object in some timezone), to convert it to other timezones and to print the times in a given time format:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pytz  # $ pip install pytz

time_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z"
tzids = ['Asia/Shanghai', 'Europe/London', 'America/New_York']
for tz in map(pytz.timezone, tzids):
    time_in_tz = aware_dt.astimezone(tz)
    print(f"{time_in_tz:{time_format}}")
```

<sup>If `f""` syntax is unavailable, you could replace it with `"".format(**vars())`</sup>

where you could set `aware_dt` from the current time in the local timezone:

```
from datetime import datetime
import tzlocal  # $ pip install tzlocal

local_timezone = tzlocal.get_localzone()
aware_dt = datetime.now(local_timezone) # the current time
```

Or from the input time string in the local timezone:

```
naive_dt = datetime.strptime(time_string, time_format)
aware_dt = local_timezone.localize(naive_dt, is_dst=None)
```

where `time_string` could look like: `'2016-11-19 02:21:42'`. It corresponds to `time_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`.

`is_dst=None` forces an exception if the input time string corresponds to a non-existing or ambiguous local time such as during a DST transition. You could also pass `is_dst=False`, `is_dst=True`. See links with more details at [Python: How do you convert datetime/timestamp from one timezone to another timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31977563/4279)

Answer (score 7):

For Python timezone conversions, I use the [handy table](http://taaviburns.ca/presentations/what_you_need_to_know_about_datetimes/) from the PyCon 2012 [presentation](https://us.pycon.org/2012/schedule/presentation/255/) by Taavi Burns.

Answer (score 6):

Please note: The first part of this answer is or version 1.x of pendulum. See below for a version 2.x answer.

I hope I'm not too late!

The [pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/) library excels at this and other date-time calculations.

```
>>> import pendulum
>>> some_time_zones = ['Europe/Paris', 'Europe/Moscow', 'America/Toronto', 'UTC', 'Canada/Pacific', 'Asia/Macao']
>>> heres_a_time = '1996-03-25 12:03 -0400'
>>> pendulum_time = pendulum.datetime.strptime(heres_a_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %z')
>>> for tz in some_time_zones:
...     tz, pendulum_time.astimezone(tz)
...     
('Europe/Paris', <Pendulum [1996-03-25T17:03:00+01:00]>)
('Europe/Moscow', <Pendulum [1996-03-25T19:03:00+03:00]>)
('America/Toronto', <Pendulum [1996-03-25T11:03:00-05:00]>)
('UTC', <Pendulum [1996-03-25T16:03:00+00:00]>)
('Canada/Pacific', <Pendulum [1996-03-25T08:03:00-08:00]>)
('Asia/Macao', <Pendulum [1996-03-26T00:03:00+08:00]>)
```

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13866926/131187) lists the names of the time zones that may be used with pendulum. (They're the same as for pytz.)

For version 2:

- `some_time_zones` is a list of the names of the time zones that might be used in a program
- `heres_a_time` is a sample time, complete with a time zone in the form '-0400'
- I begin by converting the time to a pendulum time for subsequent processing
- now I can show what this time is in each of the time zones in `show_time_zones`

...

```
>>> import pendulum
>>> some_time_zones = ['Europe/Paris', 'Europe/Moscow', 'America/Toronto', 'UTC', 'Canada/Pacific', 'Asia/Macao']
>>> heres_a_time = '1996-03-25 12:03 -0400'
>>> pendulum_time = pendulum.from_format('1996-03-25 12:03 -0400', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm ZZ')
>>> for tz in some_time_zones:
...     tz, pendulum_time.in_tz(tz)
...     
('Europe/Paris', DateTime(1996, 3, 25, 17, 3, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('Europe/Paris')))
('Europe/Moscow', DateTime(1996, 3, 25, 19, 3, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('Europe/Moscow')))
('America/Toronto', DateTime(1996, 3, 25, 11, 3, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('America/Toronto')))
('UTC', DateTime(1996, 3, 25, 16, 3, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')))
('Canada/Pacific', DateTime(1996, 3, 25, 8, 3, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('Canada/Pacific')))
('Asia/Macao', DateTime(1996, 3, 26, 0, 3, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('Asia/Macao')))
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: Pendulum is amazing, but keep in mind the output might not be compatible with whatever you want to do next, for example Pandas dataframes.

Answer (score 4):

For Python 3.2+ [simple-date](https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-date) is a wrapper around pytz that tries to simplify things.

If you have a `time` then

```
SimpleDate(time).convert(tz="...")
```

may do what you want.  But timezones are quite complex things, so it can get significantly more complicated - see the [the docs](https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-date).

Answer (score 3):

```
# Program
import time
import os

os.environ['TZ'] = 'US/Eastern'
time.tzset()
print('US/Eastern in string form:',time.asctime()) 

os.environ['TZ'] = 'Australia/Melbourne'
time.tzset()
print('Australia/Melbourne in string form:',time.asctime())

os.environ['TZ'] = 'Asia/Kolkata'
time.tzset()
print('Asia/Kolkata in string form:',time.asctime())
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and always remember that you are not only answering to the OP, but also to any future readers of this question, especially given that this one is already 8 years old. Please [edit] your post to contain some explanation as to why this would work.

Comment: @Sahil Soni - Please provide answers with proper descriptions and explanations