# Generating current time in a chosen time zone

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to perform a, to me, simple task of generating a current date/time combo at a speficic time zone. All I see is suggestions to use pytz even though datetime includes the tzinfo class to deal with timezones. However, if I try to use tzinfo, it does not work:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, tzinfo
>>> d = datetime.now(tzinfo.tzname("EDT"))
TypeError: descriptor 'tzname' requires a 'datetime.tzinfo' object but received a 'str'
```

The docs say you can use a time zone name like "EDT" or "GMT". What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`tzinfo.tzname`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) does the opposite of what you think it does.

It takes a datetime object and *returns* a string indicating the time zone.

Comment: Ah! :( So you really must use an extra module, pytz, for this?

Comment: @mart1n, It would appear so, yes. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18646797/391161).

Comment: tzinfo is an Abstract Class. This is there more for a guide than to a lever, as @merlin2011 has mentioned.