# How do I add +5 time in GMT in python?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I am matching two attributes in assembla(no DB) but one attribute save the date and time in GMT due to which I am unable to find the exact matches. I have decided to add +5 to the one which contains GMT time at runtime so the both the attributes date time will be same and I can find the exact match.

First I want to add the time so I can get the correct time, and then I am splitting the time because the other attribute doesn't contain time.

```
 abc_date = ticket['abc_date'].?
 abc_date = ticket['abc_date'].split('T')[0]
```

`abc_date: 2015/4/1 8pm` Is currently like this

`abc_date: 2015/4/2 1am` I want it like this after hours added

N.B `abc_date` is a datetime field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a python utc datetime to a local datetime using only python standard library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563272/how-to-convert-a-python-utc-datetime-to-a-local-datetime-using-only-python-stand)

Comment: take a look at this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997577/python-timezone-conversion)

Answer (score 4):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
n = datetime.now()
print n + timedelta(hours=5)
```

This code will add 5 hours to the current datetime

Comment: how will it work on this query?

abc_date = ticket['abc_date']?(here need to add timedelta or .timedelte will work)
 abc_date = ticket['abc_date'].split('T')[0]

Comment: If the `abc_date` is a datetime field as you said, you can just use `abc_date+=timedelta(hours=5)`

Comment: abc_date = ticket['abc_date'] += timedelta(hours=5)
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: after `abc_date = ticket['abc_date'] ` add `abc_date+=timedelta(hours=5)`. or `abc_date = ticket['abc_date'] + timedelta(hours=5) `.Did you even know how to write python?

Comment: i know it and i have tried this add thing before but it gives error

    abc_date = ticket['abc_date'] + timedelta(hours=5)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.timedelta found

Comment: @Javi From the error message it is clear, that `ticket['abc_date']` contains a (unicode) string. Your question states that it is a datetime object. If it's a string, you should indicate that in the question.