# Python string to Django timezone (aware datetime)

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, pytz

**TL;DR;**

How to convert `2016-01-01` to Django `timezone`?

**Full version**:

I receive a query string parameter from a form and I wanna get that string and use it as a datetime filter in Django. 
The problem is that when I convert the string to a datetime, it's not making an aware datetime and so I lose a few hours due to timezone different. Maybe I'm losing myself in the formatting, but I'm not being able to do it.

I have pytz, I have `USE_TZ = True` in my settings as well.

example:

```
from datetime import date
# Example from what I receive as GET querystring parameter
start_date, end_date = '15-01-2016', '16-01-2016'
DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'
start_date = start_date.split('-')
start_date = date(int(start_date[2]), int(start_date[1]), int(start_date[0]))
sd_filter = start_date.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)

end_date = end_date.split('-')
end_date = date(int(end_date[2]), int(end_date[1]), int(end_date[0]))
ed_filter = end_date.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)

#query
my_list = MyModel.objects.filter(created_at__range=(sd_filter, ed_filter))
```

the problem lies in the filter. I'm losing a few hours due to timezone from Django settings.

**UPDATE:** I don't need to convert a `datetime.now()` to my time. I need to convert a string to datetime.

Comment: What field type are you using in your model? A `DateField()`? If so, you can just pass the two `date` objects (`start_date` and `end_date`) to your `created_at__range=()` filter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Timezone conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997577/python-timezone-conversion)

Comment: @lambo477 It's a `DateTimeField` and I tryed doing that .. but it's still missing a few hours from utc.

Comment: @LajosArpad I tried using what was said in the answers but it didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I know this is old but maybe will be helpful since I got into this situation as well:

What about using make_aware() ?

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import make_aware

date = '22-05-2018'
aware = make_aware(datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%m-%Y'))
```

This will use the currently active timezone (activated by `timezone.activate`). If no timezone is activated explicitly, it would use the default timezone -- `TIME_ZONE` specified in `settings.py`.

Answer (score 23):

You are comparing time-zone unaware Python `Date` objects with the time-zone aware `DateTimeField` fields in your database. It is probably more intuitive to use `DateTime` objects - and these can be made time-zone aware easily as follows:

```
import datetime
import pytz

start_date = '15-01-2016' 
end_date = '16-01-2016'
date_format = '%d-%m-%Y'

unaware_start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, date_format)
aware_start_date = pytz.utc.localize(unaware_start_date)

unaware_end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, date_format)
aware_end_date = pytz.utc.localize(unaware_end_date)

my_list = MyModel.objects.filter(created_at__range=(aware_start_date, aware_end_date))
```

This creates `unaware_start_date` and `unaware_end_date` `DateTime` objects using `strptime()`. It then uses `pytz.utc.localize` to make the objects time-zone aware (you will need to replace `utc` with your relevant time-zone).

You can then have time-zone aware `DateTime` objects - `aware_start_date` and `aware_end_date`. Feeding these into your filter should yield the desired results.

Comment: If you don't have the `pytz` module installed, run `pip install pytz` from your command line

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.utils import timezone
timestamp_raw = timezone.now() #current time, or use whatever time you have
date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' #time format day-month-year hour:minutes:seconds
timestamp = timezone.datetime.strftime(timestamp_raw, date_format)
```

Or Using the new f-string formatter

```
f"{timezone:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p}"
```

Comment: Does this apply to a date ISO string?

Comment: Yes, It does . I have also edited the answer to include example using the new f-string formatter.