# Convert an arbitrary date time in one time zone and convert it to another timezone by using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, datetime, timezone

I need to convert an arbitrary datetime string for example "2015-10-01 12:20:00 UTC" and convert it to another timezone for example  "Europe/Istanbul" with using a simple code in python

I read these answers/questions:

[Python Timezone conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997577/python-timezone-conversion)

[Python - Convert UTC datetime string to local datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/python-convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime)

but they are not clear and all of them convert nowtime but I need convert any time in any timezone to another arbitrary zonetime

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily with modules *datetime* and *dateutil*:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

dobj = datetime.strptime("2015-10-01 12:20:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
dobj = dobj.replace(tzinfo=tz.gettz("UTC"))

print(dobj)
print(dobj.astimezone(tz.gettz("Europe/Istanbul")))
```

Output:

```
$ python2.7 time.py 
2015-10-01 12:20:00+00:00
2015-10-01 15:20:00+03:00
```

Comment: is there any way by using pytz instead of dateutil?

Comment: Does this account for daylight savings?