# using python convert UTC time to local time of Longitude and latitude provided

Tags: python, datetime, utc, timezone-offset

I am using sunrise-sunset api to get sunrise and sunset for day.

```
>>> url = "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=36.7201600&lng=-4.4203400&date=2017-07-31"
>>> import urllib2
>>> import json
>>> resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
>>> data = json.load(resp)
>>> sunriseUtc = data.get("results").get("sunrise")
>>> sunriseUtc
u'5:23:18 AM'
```

I want to convert this UTC time to local time of that of Long, Lat passed in the URL. i.e. not user local.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Convert UTC datetime string to local datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/python-convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime)

Comment: @Rahul I do not want to convert to local datetime

Comment: use pytz for timezone conversion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997577/python-timezone-conversion

Comment: Do you mean "local time" or "astronomical time"? Because it is not the same as local time, for example local time in Warsaw is the same as in Paris, despite large difference in astronomical time…

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that. The puzzle is to determine the country you're in from longitude and latitude, then determine that country's UTC offset, then generate the local time at those long/lat coordinates given the UTC offset.

Comment: @PatrickKeenan that is true I do have city from `wthrUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Phillaur&cnt=10&mode=json&units=metric ; response = urllib2.urlopen(wthUrl); print json.load(response).get("city");` results in `{u'country': u'IN', u'population': 0, u'id': 1259775, u'coord': {u'lat': 31.0292, u'lon': 75.7842}, u'name': u'Phillaur'}` but from jst the city name & country available I don't know how to get timezone from `from dateutil.zoneinfo import get_zonefile_instance; zonenames = list(get_zonefile_instance().zones)` as same city can b in different countries !

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a web query you might be better off using pyephem, it is `pip install pyephem` able and will give you the sunrise/set times, (and a lot more), for a given location, (lat/long), based on physical values.

```
>>> import ephem
>>> sun = ephem.Sun()
>>> greenwich = ephem.Observer()
>>> greenwich.lat = '51:28:38'
>>> print(greenwich.horizon)
0:00:00.0
>>> greenwich.date = '2007/10/1'
>>> r1 = greenwich.next_rising(sun)
>>> greenwich.pressure = 0
>>> greenwich.horizon = '-0:34'
>>> greenwich.date = '2007/10/1'
>>> r2 = greenwich.next_rising(sun)
>>> print('Visual sunrise: %s' % r1)
Visual sunrise: 2007/10/1 05:59:30
>>> print('Naval Observatory sunrise: %s' % r2)
Naval Observatory sunrise: 2007/10/1 05:59:50
```

Comment: well I will give it a try , however I would prefer accuracy

Comment: I think that you will find the accuracy of pyephem is very high accuracy if used correctly. Plus of course it will work offline.

Comment: It also has conversion between utc and time at observer position.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 3.8:

To Begin add the following modules below:

> > > import time
> > >
> > > from time import localtime

Next, call  on the localtime() method and insert your time (in this case, variable "sunriseUtc"):

> > > localtime(sunriseUtc).

That's it.

If you would like to format the time (how it is presented) you will need to import strftime (abbreviated for string format time) from the time module. Then set up the format for your time. Then pass the same argument from above:
e.g.

> > > from time import strftime
> > >
> > > strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", localtime(sunriseUtc))

'05/12/2019 05:57:05 AM'

This worked for me when using the requests module to download data from the openweathermap.org's API.

If you need more support, see time module's documentation:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime

Note: My project was built on the example from "Project: Fetching Current Weather Data" found here:
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter14/

[python](/questions/tagged/python)[datetime-conversion](/questions/tagged/datetime-conversion)