# How to get current time in a specific timezone?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the datetime module as follows to get the current time:

```
 datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
```

And this gives me the current time but in UTC. How can I get the current time in CST ?
Can I do that without using other external libraries or is it easier to use something else?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Timezone conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997577/python-timezone-conversion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be tricky without an external library, so i suggest you use the `pytz` package

```
pip install pytz
```

And with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997577/python-timezone-conversion) you could try something like below

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

now_time = datetime.now(timezone('America/Chicago'))
print(now_time.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p'))
```

I used `America/Chicago` because it's in the CDT timezone according to [this](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cdt).

But if you are interested in doing it natively you will have to read up some more [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html) in the official documentation because it provide some examples on how to do it but it will leave kicking and screaming especially if you are a beginner.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed to know, whether it's worth doing it natively haha

Comment: Things got easier in 3.9. [My answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74237887/1045881)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it without an external library or hard-coding the offset

```py
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
time_stamp = datetime.now(ZoneInfo('America/Chicago'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this solution depends on the module `pytz`

```
import pytz
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Central')))
```

In case you need to know all available timezones

```
for tz in pytz.all_timezones:
    print(tz)
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate it :)

Comment: It did, but it doesn't any more

Comment: @toddmo In which condition does it not?