# Converting time zone from utc to america/new_york on a dictionary using python

Tags: python, dictionary, pytz

I have a dictionary of timestamps which are strings which I first converted to datetime objects. 
I need to do the sql equivalent of `timestamp at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'America/New_York'`
Here I have a for loop

```
 for x in dataj:
     x['event_time'] = datetime.strptime(x['event_time'].split('.')[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
     x['event_time'] = x['event_time'].replace(tzinfo=timezone('America/New_York'))
```

I get this error

```
 TypeError: timezone() argument 1 must be datetime.timedelta, not str
```

dataj looks like so:

```
P(dataj[0])
{'$insert_id': '14ae91db-4b9e-4898-88dd-62fc9f99dcb4',
 '$schema': 12,
 'adid': None,
 'event_time': '2019-12-01 00:00:19.251000'
 }
```

Comment: can you show your dataj ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using `pytz.timezone` and not `datetime.timezone` ?

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997577/python-timezone-conversion/18646797#18646797) shows how to add the needed timezones to the datetime object. You need to use `pytz`.

Here is a segment that is similar to your post.

```
import datetime
import pytz
x = '2019-12-01 00:00:19.251000'
as_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(x.split('.')[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
as_datetime # datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 1, 0, 0, 19)

utcmoment = as_datetime.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
as_nytz = utcmoment.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))
as_nytz # datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 30, 19, 0, 19, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EST-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing all background...

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone
import pytz

dataj = {'$insert_id': '14ae91db-4b9e-4898-88dd-62fc9f99dcb4','$schema': 12, 'adid': None,'event_time': '2019-12-01 00:00:19.251000'}

print(dataj)

for schema, value in dataj.items():
    if schema == 'event_time':
        correct_time = datetime.strptime(dataj["event_time"].split('.')[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        dataj['event_time'] = correct_time.replace(tzinfo=timezone('America/New_York'))

print(dataj)
```