# Python convert raw GMT to othertime zone e.g SGT

Tags: python, python-datetime

I am trying to convert from GMT to e.g SGT:

For example, the value

0348 GMT should be 11:48 am
1059 GMT should be 6:59 pm

how do i do this?

i have tried:

```
date="03:48"
curr = (
    dt.datetime.strptime(date, "%H:%M")

    .astimezone(timezone('Asia/Singapore'))
)
print(curr)
```

But I am getting OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997577/python-timezone-conversion

Comment: Did you try anything? Have a look at e.g. `dateutil` to get a time zone? For SGT, you'll have to use the name 'Asia/Singapore'.

Comment: @MrFuppesi updated it

Comment: i do not have the date but the time in that form only

Comment: @AmeyaRane: `pytz` is [to be deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/), use `dateutil` instead, or `zoneinfo` with Python 3.9.

Comment: your example is missing a date, it's just a time! without a date, timezone information is ambiguous due to DST (except GMT/UTC)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a [naive datetime object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects) which represents UTC:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from dateutil import tz

now = datetime.now()
print(repr(now))
>>> datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 28, 8, 5, 42, 553781)
```

Make sure to set the `tzinfo` property to UTC using [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace):

```
now_utc_aware = now.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
print(repr(now_utc_aware))
>>> datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 28, 8, 5, 42, 553781, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Now you can convert to another timezone using [astimezone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone):

```
now_sgt = now_utc_aware.astimezone(tz.gettz('Asia/Singapore'))
print(repr(now_sgt))
>>> datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 28, 16, 5, 42, 553781, tzinfo=tzfile('Singapore'))
```

---

***Sidenote***, referring to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63126322/how-to-convert-datetime-object-python-to-current), if you parse correctly, you already get an aware datetime object:

```
date = "2020-07-27T16:38:20Z"
dtobj = datetime.fromisoformat(date.replace('Z', '+00:00'))
print(repr(dtobj))
>>> datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 27, 16, 38, 20, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```