# Storing Datetime object in Pandas Dataframe as IsoDate

Tags: python, mongodb, dataframe, datetime, isodate

**Scenario**: I have a dataframe 'df' with multiple columns. In this I add a column 'date' of type '**<class 'datetime.datetime'>**' .

`df['date'] = datetime.datetime.now()`

Then I am storing this in MongoDB using

```
db.collection.insert_many(df.to_dict('records'))
```

**Problem**:  So after storing into db I'm getting type of 'date' column as **Date**, But I need to have **ISODate** type.

Comment: maybe `iso_strs = dt_col.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")` ?

Comment: when viewing in mongodb compass it shows Date as type, when querying result using pymongo it shows Datetime. I need like this "ISODate("2020-07-26T16:44:41.916Z")"

Comment: Are you passing string to Date?

Comment: maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63149963/10197418

Comment: I m not dealing with strings anywhere, I need my Datetime object into dataframe, and that to IsoDate in mongodb