# Convert UTC+0 to other time zone Python

Tags: python

I have a time string obtained from API, it's UTC+0. I would like to change to other time zone.
I have tried below but it doesn't work. Could you please give me some idea ? many thanks.

```
utc0time='2021-04-17T15:50:14.614646+00:00'
dt = datetime.strptime('utc0time', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'). #it results as an error, not match the format
time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
calendar.timegm(dt.timetuple())
```

Comment: That won't work because the string `'utc0time`' is not even *close* to a legal time expression.  You need to use the variable, not a string of the same characters.

Comment: Have you tried using `pytz`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997577/python-timezone-conversion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Timezone conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10997577/6045800)

Answer (score 1):

You could actually use `timedelta` in `datetime` module to +/- number of hours to achieve the time in other timezone you wish.

Here is an example where you can use `timedelta`:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-datetime-timedelta-function/

Comment: Sure, but `pytz` is more robust as once can specify the timezone rather than have to look up the differences.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the comments and it gave me the idea. Because i only need to convert from one time zone to another one, i don't need to convert to multi-timezone. I don't use pytz this time. I used a silly method, changed the str to timestamp first, then used timedelta to adjust the hours. Below is my final code.

```
utc0time='2021-04-17T15:50:14.614646+00:00'
utc0time = utc0time[:-13]
timestamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(utc0time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))
datatimeformat = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
utc8time = datatimeformat + timedelta(hours = 8)
```