# convert random string to datetime in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, datetime-format

I have extracted data with date formatted `28-12-2019 19:13 +07:00`  and it was not recognize as datetime by Pandas. how can I create new column with column name `creation_date`  and add the correct datetime format.

i tried this but error

```
data = 'data.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(data)

df['creation_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str[:2] + '-' + df['date'].str[4:2] + '-' + df['date'].str[7:4])

print(df)
```

i want the format to be recognized in excel which is `12/28/2019  08:13:00 PM`. +1 hour since my GMT is +8

Comment: What do you mean by `089:13:00 PM`?

Comment: ah my bad, i mean ```08:13:00 PM```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written the below solution for a single string. In your case, you'll need to adapt it for your whole data frame column.

First of all, you need to convert the string containing date and time to a `datetime` object.

You can do this using following code:

```
import datetime
Date = "28-12-2019 19:13 +07:00"
datetimeObj = datetime.datetime.strptime(Date, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M %z")
```

Which will give you a `datetime` object like this:

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 28, 19, 13, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=25200)))
```

The next thing you'll need to do is, convert this `datetime` object to your preferred timezone.

For that you can use the following code:

```
datetimeObj.astimezone(ZoneInfo('Europe/London'))
```

**Note:**

1. I've considered `London` for the sake of demonstration. You'll need to choose it accordingly.
2. The above solution will work only if you have `Python 3.9+` installed. If you have any other version installed, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997577/python-timezone-conversion) answer.

The next thing you'll need to do is formatting the `datetime` object so that it represents date and time in a way you want.

```
datetimeObj = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetimeObj, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

This will produce the following output:

```
'12/28/2019 12:13'
```

Comment: Thanks Man, that helps me alot. 

I follow your instruction and apply lambda to my series

```df['cerated_at'] = df['created_at'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M %z')).apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%M-%d-%Y %H:%M'))```

thank you

Comment: Great! Happy to help!!